# Trouble using SFML with GCC and OS X

Tags: c++, linker, sfml

I've been trying to get SFML working for a while now and I've been trying to get it working using GCC. I'm on OS X by the way. I followed the standard Linux instructions and using the Linux 64-bit download however when it comes to compiling...

```
g++ -o testing main.cpp -lsfml-system
```

This happens:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7: error: ‘class sf::Clock’ has no member named ‘GetElapsedTime’
main.cpp:9: error: ‘class sf::Clock’ has no member named ‘GetElapsedTime’
main.cpp:10: error: ‘Sleep’ is not a member of ‘sf’
```

So I thought it could be due to not using includes, so I changed my gcc compile command to:

```
 g++ -o testing main.cpp -I ~/SFML-1.6/include/ -lsfml-system
```

and now I'm getting this error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system.so, file was built for     unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sf::Clock::Clock()", referenced from:
      _main in ccZEiB7b.o
  "sf::Clock::GetElapsedTime() const", referenced from:
      _main in ccZEiB7b.o
  "sf::Sleep(float)", referenced from:
      _main in ccZEiB7b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**
```

And I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Comment: You're mixing 32bit and 64bit objects. Where did you download the 64bit libraries to?

Comment: I still have them in the SFML-1.6 folder, but they look like this: "libsfml-system.so.1.6" should i just rename them sfml-system.so or what?

Comment: Nonono, don't rename shared libraries. Look at your second error message closely and see if the file being picked up is the one you want (i.e. the 64bit one you downloaded). If not, use the  `-L` flag to tell GCC where to look for the shared objects.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand fully what i need to do, i've found the sfml libs but i don't know where the 64 bit versions of those are.

Comment: You say you downloaded the 64bit version, surely you know where you put them?

Comment: i don't see any sfml-system libs in the package i downloaded though

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

Add the `-arch i386` (on mac) or `-m32` (on linux) flag

### Long answer

Your `sfml-system` library was built in 32 bits whereas you are trying to compile your program in 64 bits. So your program cannot link to the library.

Recompile SFML in 64 bits if possible and you should be able to compile your program in 64 bits.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback! I'll go try recompiling it now.

Comment: Try `-m32` instead of `-arch i386` (my mistake!). Otherwise, can you post the new errors you get? (you can edit your question for that)

Answer (score 0):

SFML expects you to use frameworks on OS X. Open the SFML folder and copy all the folders under lib64 to /Library/Frameworks (that is, copy SFML.framework, sfml-system.framework, etc. to /Library/Frameworks).

Once you've installed the frameworks, you can use them by passing the -framework command to g++ like so:

```
g++ -o testing main.cpp -framework SFML -framework sfml-system
```